# Catching keydown event on Google Presentation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, content-script

I want to catch `keydown` event on Google Presentation using Chrome extension. I checked my contents scripts were inserted to the google presentation scripts, but catching `keydown` events are not working even if I stroke a key. I also tried `monitorEvents(document)` in Chrome console, and it seems Google Presentation does not generate `keydown` events. Could you please help me?

Comment: The events are triggered inside an iframe with a class attribute containing `docs-texteventtarget-iframe` so you need to register the listener inside that iframe's contentDocument property.

Comment: That saved my time! Thanks!